# Importing multiple files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm trying to create a script where the user can select 1 or all files in a folder (to "imitate" the multi-selection open of *uigetfile* in Matlab). Afterwards, the script will ask if the user wants to import data from another location and the import 1 or all routine continues.

The mission of the script is just to retrieve the path and file names for a multi-selection option. It was written on a PC using Windows 10, with Python 3.6 and Spyder as a IDE in the Anaconda Distro.

So far I have this:

```
def import_multiple_files(): 
    # Similar to UIGETFILE
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import glob


    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.lift()
    file_location = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    a=file_location.split('/')
    path=[]
    for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
        path.append(a[i])

    path= "/".join(path)    
    filename=a[len(a)-1]

    # Questions the user

    qst=messagebox.askyesno("Multiple Import","Do you want to import all .txt files in this folder?")
    allFiles=[]

    if qst==True:

    # Gets all .txt files in path FOLDER

        b=glob.glob(path + "/*.txt") # glob. lists the filename and path

        allFiles.append(b)
    else: 
        b=(path + "/"+ filename)
        allFiles.append(b)

    qst=messagebox.askyesno("Multiple Import","Do you want to import more DATA?")   


    finish=0    
    while finish==0:
        if qst==True:

        # deletes all variables except "AllFILES" (location of all files to import)
            del(root,file_location,a,path,qst,b)

            root = tk.Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            root.attributes("-topmost", True)
            root.lift()
            file_location = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            a=file_location.split('/')
            path=[]
            for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
                path.append(a[i])

            path= "/".join(path)    
            filename=a[len(a)-1]

            qst=messagebox.askyesno("Multiple Import","Do you want to import all .txt files in this folder?")

            if qst==True:
                # Gets all .txt files in path FOLDER
                b=glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
                allFiles.append(b)
                qst=messagebox.askyesno("Multiple Import","Do you want to import more DATA?") 
            else: 
                b=(path + "/"+ filename)
                allFiles.append(b)
                qst=messagebox.askyesno("Multiple Import","Do you want to import more DATA?") 

        else:
            finish=1

    return(allFiles)


file_location=import_multiple_files()
```

The script/function returns the full path and file name, however, some of the names came with a double backslash for some reason

e.g,

```
file_location
[['C:/Users/user/Desktop/New Folder (2)\\1.txt',
  'C:/Users/user/Desktop/New Folder (2)\\2.txt',
  'C:/Users/user/Desktop/New Folder (2)\\3.txt'],
 ['C:/Users/user/Desktop/New Folder (3)/1.txt']] # For this last file, I did not select the option of importing all files.
```

Can anyone be so kind as to take a look to this script and see if something is wrong, or if this is just the way Python displays things.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you include the code that prints out the filenames? (Also it would be better to explicitly mention in the question that this is on Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\\` is just the way Python shows an escaped backslash. `\` is used in a number of contexts for signifying a new line (`\n`), a tab (`\t`) etc. So `\\` just indicates that whatever appears after the backslash is not one of these special characters.
Python will make sense of your mixture of forward and backslashes but if you want to have everything display consistently, you can use `[os.path.abspath(d) for d in my_list]`.

Also, it looks like you should be using `extend` instead of `append` if you want to avoid creating a list of lists.

Comment: Hi. 

Thank you for the answer!

In fact the .extend is a better approach! 
the piece of code you suggested `[os.path.abspath(d) for d in file_location]` puts double backslashes in everything ehehhe.
I´m still quite new in programming in general. I will wait one day, If no one else replies I will accept your answer and post the last version of the code.

Comment: Yes it does this because you're using Windows. If you try on Mac or Linux you will get single forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "final" version

Thank you all!

This function retrieves the file location of 1 or all files in a folder.

```
def import_multiple_files(): 
    # 'similar' to UIGETFILE
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import glob
    import os

    # Creates a Tkinter window to search for a file
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.lift()
    file_location = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    a=file_location.split('/')

    # Separates the file location into path and file name
    path=[]
    for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
        path.append(a[i])

    path= "/".join(path)    
    filename=a[len(a)-1]

    # Questions the user

    qst=messagebox.askyesno("Multiple Import","Do you want to import all .txt files in this folder?")


    allFiles=[]

    if qst==True:

    # Gets all .txt files in path FOLDER

        b=glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")

        allFiles.extend(b)
    else: 
        b=[(path + "/"+ filename)]
        allFiles.extend(b)

    # Questions the user
    qst=messagebox.askyesno("Multiple Import","Do you want to import more DATA?")   

    # Allows the user to import as many files from as as many folders as he/she chooses     
    finish=0    
    while finish==0:
        if qst==True:

        # deletes all variables except "AllFILES" (location of all files to import)
            del(root,file_location,a,path,qst,b)

            root = tk.Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            root.attributes("-topmost", True)
            root.lift()
            file_location = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            a=file_location.split('/')
            path=[]
            for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
                path.append(a[i])

            path= "/".join(path)    
            filename=a[len(a)-1]

            qst=messagebox.askyesno("Multiple Import","Do you want to import all .txt files in this folder?")

            if qst==True:
                # Gets all .txt files in path FOLDER
                b=glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
                allFiles.extend(b)
                qst=messagebox.askyesno("Multiple Import","Do you want to import more DATA?") 
            else: 
                b=[(path + "/"+ filename)]
                allFiles.extend(b)
                qst=messagebox.askyesno("Multiple Import","Do you want to import more DATA?") 

        else:
            finish=1

        b=[os.path.abspath(d) for d in allFiles]
    # Returns all file locations    
    return(b)
```